# Why nodes and lines are invisible on plotting?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to label the origin `O(0,0)`, the point `A(1,0)` and to draw a dashed line on the plottings of two functions, using

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
       [
         axis lines=middle,
         axis equal image,
         xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
         ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
         xtick={6}, ytick={6}, no marks,  xmin=-1, xmax=5, ymin=-1, ymax=2, 
         enlargelimits={upper=0.1},
       ]
         \addplot [blue,domain=0:1] {-2*x^2+3*x};
         \addplot [red,domain=1:5] {1/x};
         \addplot [black,domain=0:5] {1/(x+1)};
         \draw node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
         \draw node[below left] at (1,0) {$A$};
         \draw[style=densely dotted,color=black](1,0) -- (1,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I get 
[image]

Why `O`, `A`, and the line are invisible and how could I fix this ?

Comment: Try adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`, or use `(axis cs:0,0)` instead of `(0,0)` for the node coordinate. With compat settings below version 1.11 axis coordinates are not used for `\draw`, `\node` etc. without the `axis cs` prefix.

Comment: Thank you! It worked well with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`.

Comment: One should take into account that the axis environment runs through the code twice, the first time to determine the scale and limits to use when plotting.  Older versions required one to use \pgfplotsextra or put all the normal tikz commands outisde the axis environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.